# Using For loop to calculate

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, cs50

"I want to multiply every second digit by 2 and sum them up in the program. For example, in the case of the input value 1234, this means multiplying 3 and 1 by 2 and summing them up, which results in 8. However, the current output of the program is other. How can I fix this?"
(input value should be 1111111111111111 and its output is -628319165)

how to fix the problem

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long number, x, y;
    int fn;
    int z = 0;
    do
    {
        number = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while(number < 1000000000000 || number >10000000000000000);

    for (x = 100; x <1000000000000000000; x=x*100 )
    {
        y =number%x ;
        for(  long j = 10; j == x/10; j=j*100)
        {
            y = y/j;
            y = y*2;
            fn=0;
            


        }
        if(y / 10 == 1)
        {
            fn = y%10;
            fn= fn+ 1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            fn = y ;
        }
        z = z+fn;
        
    }
    printf("%d\n",z);

}
```

Comment: Please, be aware of the *limits* of what different types of numbers can represent. You can't just smash in an arbitrary number of digits and expect it to work.

Comment: PSA: If this is to validate credit card numbers, **treat the data as a series of digits** and not an actual integer value.

Comment: Even if not, you may find it very useful to treat it as a string, rather than an integer.

Comment: @Guy 1) use `long long` instead of `long`.  2) To the bottom of the `for()` loop, add `if (x > LLONG_MAX/100) break;` to prevent overflow with `x=x*100`.  3) perhaps other changes needed too.

Comment: @tadman: The [instructions for the assignment](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/1/credit/) specifically recommend to use `get_long`, which implies that the credit card number should be stored in a `long int`. This should not be a problem, provided that a `long int` is at least 64 bits wide (which is untrue on some platforms, most notably Microsoft Windows).

Comment: You wrote: "the current output of the program is other". Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the actual output you get and the expected output. When I try to use the value `1234`, the program asks again, probably because the condition `number < 1000000000000` is true. You might get other results if the size of `long` is different on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

As others said in the comments, the problem is that on your system the types are not large enough to hold the values. Keep in mind that in all C integers have a maximum and minimum value that it can hold. You can get this limits from the header standard `limits.h` (or see here https://cplusplus.com/reference/climits/). The standard guarantees that the maximum of a `int` is at least `2**15-1 = 32767` and the maximum of a `long` is at least `2**15-1 = 2147483647` Your numbers are bigger than that.

While you could use a `long long` with the minimum limit of `2**63-1 = 9223372036854775807`, which is large enough for your purpose, i would suggest to work with a string or a other array instead for this kind of task. You could get the value of a single digit in a string like this: `unsigned digit = string[position]-'0';`. You have to substract `'0'` from it because the digit `'0'` starts most likely not at 0 but at 0x30. The rest of the implementation is up to you. And don't forget to check if the character is actually a digit before you read its value.